# Javascript ES6: Create a id-value object from list

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do i create an Object from an array with Javascript es6?

Length of uniqYears array is flexible, hence, I don't want to hard-code the IDs for each year. I do not have a list of indexes to start with.

```
const uniqYears = [2016, 2017]
```

Desired output:

```
const uniqYearsObj = [
  { id: 1, year: 2016 },
  { id: 2, year: 2017 }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: oops, you're not new

Comment: I've added an answer for you. is that helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by many ways e.g `forEach()`, `map()` and so on...... With simple `forEach()`,

Using **Array.prototype.map()**,

```js
const uniqYears = [2016, 2017]
const result = [];
uniqYears.map((e, i) =>result.push({id: i+1, year: e}))
console.log(result);
```

Using **Array.prototype.forEach()**,

```js
const uniqYears = [2016, 2017]
const result = [];
uniqYears.forEach((e, i) =>result.push({id: i+1, year: e}))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: specific reason for voting it down?

Comment: Not my dv, but why `.forEach()` when this is exactly the use case for `.map()`?

Comment: @Andreas Yes I agreed sir, Added  both ways using `map()` and `forEach()` :)

Answer (score 2):

There you go:

```js
const uniqYears = [2016, 2017]

const uniqYearsObj = uniqYears.map((y, index) => ({id: index + 1, year:y }) )

console.log(uniqYearsObj)
```